# When i'm trying to add new organization in existing channel of 3 organization

Tags: shell, docker, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to add new organization (org4) with 2 peers in a channel of 3 organizations (org1, org2 and org3 respectively) having 2 peers each. While doing that using `configtxlator` tool in docker cli container I'm getting this error while getting signature from 3rd organization (org3):

```
Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- Error authorizing update: Error validating ReadSet: Readset expected key [Groups] /Channel/Application at version 1, but got version 2
```

Other two organizations are signing the addition of org4 but only org3 is giving the error. Any ideas why and how can I solve this problem.

Comment: please provide more details of the steps you took leading up to this error.

Comment: Following https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/hyperledger-fabric/latest/hyperledger-fabric.pdf this documentation of Hyperldger fabric Chap. 10 Page 5 Reconfig Our First Network. In this we are adding org3 to an existing network already having org1,2 and 1 channel (mychannel). I took bit liberty and made changes in existing scripts of first-network to create an organization with org1,2,3 and then i tried adding org 4 and created different channel also (mychannel, mychannel1, mychannel2). .

Comment: In my new network org1,2 are signing approval to ad org4 but org3 is giving error when trying to add org4 to my channel (it contains all orgs 1,2,3 and I have to add org4)